# How to remove Angular default alert error message

Tags: angular

I have a back-end micro-service in java that handles the form validation with annotation (@NotBlank...).
I have made the front-end using Angular.

the validation logic is working fine.
The problem I have is that my browser or angular is generating a message box similar to the one you get with an alert() javascript function, when there is an error in the form (such as an empty fied)

(I'd post an image if I were allowed).

I don't know where that message box is coming from, I have not coded it.
At the moment I'm simply asking angular to log the message error (it works fine)

my code:

```
save() {
    this.service.addOne(this.protection).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigate(['/protections']).then();
        this.messageContainer = this.flashService.getMessageLang();
        this.flashService.defineFlash(this.messageContainer.ADDPROTECTION.SUCCESS, 1, "flash-message-green");
      },
      response => {
        if (response && response.error) {
          console.log('===========================================>');
          console.log(response.error.errors);
          ;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I would like to get rid of that message box.

I'm not even sure if this is a issue with Angular or the browser.

I tried searching the web for answers but came back empty handed. It's possible I'm not wording my search correctly since I'm not exactly where is error is coming from.

Any idea how to get rid of the message box?

Comment: what message is being displayed into the box? It might help you to find the source.

Comment: it just says : "localhost:5000 indique" and then "error returned" (indique is french for "to state")

Comment: If you can't take a screenshot of your own work you could always create a minimal replication in stackblitz or similar to share. But I think I know what you mean and have added an answer below.

Comment: I can take a screenshot I just can't post it on StackOverflow because I do not have enough reputation point.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a default [Error Handler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) which logs errors and a stacktrace, as well as showing the error screen (which I assume is the 'message box' you are describing.

You can change the default behaviour by adding your own custom error handler. Instructions and examples in the docs link above and at:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/expecting-the-unexpected-best-practices-for-error-handling-in-angular-21c3662ef9e4

Answer (score 0):

What are these lines in your code?

```
this.messageContainer = this.flashService.getMessageLang();
this.flashService.defineFlash(this.messageContainer.ADDPROTECTION.SUCCESS, 1, "flash-message-green");
```

Try commenting them?

Comment: Yes I could and should comment them however they aren't related to the problem.